# How to prevent multiple sessions from same user

Tags: authentication, login

We are using Sitecore 10.1.2
The CMS uses both native & Azure AD logins.
A user is able to login to the CMS in multiple simultaneous sessions/browsers/from different IPs.

Is it possible to prevent this by any config setting. If it is a custom implementation, please provide any pointers on where and how to achieve this.

Comment: What if you want to prevent the second login attempt? I think that's the more secure objective here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new processor to validate a single session on `<owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>` pipeline, if the same username is already logged in on other devices, we kick out the session and then remove the user's ticket from Sitecore TicketManager.

```
App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config

<configuration>
    <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
    
    <owin.cookieAuthentication.signIn>
        <processor resolve="true" type="your.SIGN-IN.pipeline, YourDLL" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignIn.RemoveTicket, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']" />
</owin.cookieAuthentication.signIn>
    
    </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
    </configuration>
```

Create `ValidateSingleSession` class inherit from `SignedInProcessor`

```
using System;
using Sitecore.Abstractions;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn;
using Sitecore.Web.Authentication;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Sitecore.SitecoreExtensions.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines
{
    public class ValidateSingleSession : SignedInProcessor
    {
        protected BaseTicketManager TicketManager { get; }
        public ValidateSingleSession(BaseTicketManager ticketManager)
        {
            this.TicketManager = ticketManager;
        }
        public override void Process(SignedInArgs args)
        {
            if (!string.Equals(args.Site.Name, "shell", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                return;

            var validateSingleSession = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("Security.ValidateSingleSession");
            if (!bool.Parse(validateSingleSession))
                return;

            List<DomainAccessGuard.Session> userSessionList = DomainAccessGuard.Sessions;

            if (userSessionList != null && userSessionList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DomainAccessGuard.Session userSession in userSessionList.ToArray())
                {
                    if (args.User.UserName == userSession.UserName)
                    {
                        DomainAccessGuard.Kick(userSession.SessionID);
                        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Audit($"Concurrent sessions detected: User {userSession.UserName} is kicked out ", this);
                    }
                }

            }

            //remove ticket 
            var ticketIds = this.TicketManager.GetTicketIDs();
            if (ticketIds != null && ticketIds.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var ticketID in ticketIds)
                {
                    var ticket = this.TicketManager.GetTicket(ticketID);
                    if (args.User.UserName == ticket.UserName)
                    {
                        this.TicketManager.RemoveTicket(ticketID);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Also created a field to allow the development team to disable single-session validation by introducing `Security.ValidateSingleSession` setting in config.

For more detailes visit the link - https://edwenkerk.hashnode.dev/sitecore-10-single-login-session-and-kick-idle-user